# Fn key doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad E14

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, lenovo, function-keys

I have a Lenovo E14 Gen 2 (type 20T6, 20T7) Laptop (ThinkPad) - Type 20T6,

On the BIOS menu, the Fn key and its dependencies work.

But when I launch Ubuntu 20.04 and start gnome, the Fn key and its shortcuts do not work.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue with an apparent BIOS bug/quirk.  If you suspend then wake up the fn keys will start working.  i just updated to the latest BIOS and issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the specific model. I found the solution [here](https://esc.sh/blog/thinkpad-e-14-fn-key/)

Basically you open crontab

```bash
sudo crontab -e
```

and add the following line

```bash
@reboot sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 2
```